# Extract lines from a text file but only the lines with IDs which are listed in a separate text file on linux

Tags: linux

Do you know how to extract lines from a text file but only the lines with IDs which are listed in a separate text file? The codes as below did not work.

```
grep -Fwf ID.txt Table.txt > Output.txt
```

Btw, ID.txt is like this. 37 lines.

```
001
003
005
```

Table.txt is as below. Multiple lines.

```
001 234
002 478
003 789
004 822
005 889
006 773
etc
```

The desired output is as below.

```
001 234
003 789
005 889
```

Comment: Do you mean that `oo1` in ID.txt "is the equivalent" of `001` in table.txt? Or you have to match exactly `oo1` in table.txt?

Comment: this is probably a typo, you mean "001" to "003" in `ID.txt`, right? If yes, this is a perfect job for the `join` program. Read its manpage.

Comment: Can you show the desired output? `grep -Ff ID.txt Table.txt` should be the correct tool.

Comment: Thank you all. I have just edited the question.

Comment: Thank you Icarus, but it also does not work. It shows only 003 789.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490711/linux-how-to-extract-rows-of-certain-ids-and-the-ids-are-writtein-in-another-fi　This works, but why grep does not work??